# How to Increase the thickness of the box lines in an R boxplot?

Tags: r, plot, boxplot

How can I increase the thickness of the lines that outline "box" part of a boxplot using either the base R plot or boxplot function?  That is, how do I thicken the lines of the box that defines the quantiles.

For a plot like this:

```
boxplot(rnorm(100,50,10), horizontal = TRUE, notch = TRUE)
```

I'm guessing I need to include a `pars =` statement like

```
boxplot(rnorm(100,50,10), horizontal = TRUE, notch = TRUE, pars = ...)
```

EDIT: 
My guess regarding the use of `pars =` comes from a first glance at the documentation for `boxplot` which indicates that `pars =` can call "a list of (potentially many) more graphical parameters, e.g., boxwex or outpch; these are passed to bxp (if plot is true)..."

Comment: If you were asking how to pass something to 'pars' to affect the features of the "boxes" inside the plot area it could be as a 'named list': `boxplot(rnorm(100,50,10), horizontal = TRUE, notch = TRUE, pars=list( boxlwd = 4))` , .... but you made the question more general to apply to either `plot` or `boxplot`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

See the `boxlwd` parameter as discussed in `?bxp` (linked to from `?boxplot`). E.g.

```
boxplot(rnorm(100,50,10), horizontal = TRUE, notch = TRUE, boxlwd = 4)
```

Answer (score 4):

Are you talking about the rectangle that surrounds the plot area? If so, then this can follow you plot call:

```
 box(lwd=5)
```

Comment: Or if they mean the lines of the boxes themselves, `boxlwd`, as clearly stated in `?bxp` which is linked to from `?boxplot`.

Comment: Since he was already asking about `pars` parameters and that parameter is not particularly common for passing arguments to par(), I figured it needed to be more obscure.

Comment: No, no particular interest in pars; that was just my initial guess based on the help file.  Thanks for the help.