# How to specify line thickness in points a plot?

Tags: r, plot, axis

The base R plot functions commonly use the argument `lwd` for specifying the line thickness. These are relative line widths though, and different help files indicate that this is a multiplying factor. So a linewidth `lwd = 1` gives a line width of `1 * defaultwidth`.

Where do I specify the default width for the line, or how can I make sure a line is eg specifically 0.75pt, as set in other software like Excel?

Comment: Had the question, solved it myself, dropped it here for reference. Feel free to add to my answer, I'm still not 100% sure if I understood it all correctly.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

The default line width is dependent on the device used for the plotting. In order to read this information, you should be aware of the general interpretation of inches, points and pixels. The general rules are:

- a point is 1/72 of an inch
- a pixel is standard 1/96 of an inch, or 0.75 points.

This can depend however on the settings of your device:

- the `pdf()` and `postscript()` devices:

  - standard a point is seen as 1/72 inch
  - `lwd = 1` refers to a linewidth of 1/96 inch or 0.75 points.
- the `png()`, `jpeg()`, `tiff()` and `bmp()` devices:

  - standard a point is seen as 1/72 inch
  - this can be chanced by setting the argument `res` which defines the ppi (points per inch).
  - `lwd = 1` is 1/96 of an inch but takes the settings of `res` into account. So if `res = 96`, `lwd = 1` is a thickness of 1pt, but your point is interpreted smaller than a regular point.

Also keep in mind that with the bitmap devices, a higher setting of `res` will blow up your figure on screen. So in the previous example, a `lwd = 1` with a setting of `res = 96` gives a line with a thickness of 1pt, but shown on the same screen this will increase the line thickness from 1 pixel to 1.33 pixels. If you scale both figures to be exactly the same size, they look the same (apart from the resolution obviously).

See also:

[How do I specify axis thickness in a plot? (in R)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16335573/how-do-i-specify-axis-thickness-in-a-plot-in-r)

[Increasing the thickness of box lines in an R boxplot?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12485744/increasing-the-thickness-of-box-lines-in-an-r-boxplot)

https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/199/point-vs-pixel-what-is-the-difference

Comment: for me, `lwd=1` is too thin, `lwd=2` is too thick and it makes no difference using decimal values. Is there a `res` parameter that can be set? @JorisMeys

Comment: @xm1 PDF doesn't have a res as that doesn't make sense in a vectorized image. You can try to set the `cex` parameter in your plotting, or `pointsize` in the `pdf()` function to get the result you want.

Comment: I am plotting (`bxp`) to screen (RStudio) and using `lines` to add the "thick" line. It seems `cex` makes no difference to `lines`. Tks!